# Delay initial running/starting of Swiper.js autoplay

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

I have a Swiper.js carousel that autoplays. I also fade in my page using `DOMContentLoaded`. This means that the first slide has changed or is in the middle of changing when the page comes into view. So it's in view a much shorter amount of time compared to the others.

Is it possible to delay the initial running of the autoplay carousel? I know you can add a delay to individual slides - but if I do that to counter it, it means 2nd time around the first slide lags/is in view longer than the rest.

JavaScript code:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.body.className = 'visible';
});

var caption = document.querySelector('.swiper-caption span');

new Swiper('.swiper', {
    // Disable preloading of all images
    preloadImages: true,
    // Enable lazy loading
    lazy: false,
    effect: 'fade',
    fadeEffect: {
        crossFade: true
    },
    loop: true,
    autoplay: {
        delay: 1200,
        disableOnInteraction: false,
        pauseOnMouseEnter: true
    },
    navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev'
    },
    pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        type: 'fraction'
    },
    on: {
        init: function() {
            updateCaptionText(this);
        },
        activeIndexChange: function() {
            updateCaptionText(this);
        }
    }
});

function updateCaptionText(slider) {
    caption.textContent = slider.slides[slider.activeIndex].dataset.caption;
}
```

CSS code:

```
body.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
}

body.visible {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .48s .24s ease-out;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `swiper.autoplay.stop()` just after setting it up, and  call `swiper.autoplay.start()` inside `DOMContentLoaded` event handler. Like so:

```js
const swiper = new Swiper(".swiper", {
  // Disable preloading of all images
  preloadImages: true,
  // Enable lazy loading
  lazy: false,
  effect: "fade",
  fadeEffect: {
    crossFade: true,
  },
  loop: true,
  autoplay: {
    delay: 1200,
    disableOnInteraction: false,
    pauseOnMouseEnter: true,
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
  },
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
    type: "fraction",
  },
  on: {
    init: function () {
      updateCaptionText(this);
    },
    activeIndexChange: function () {
      updateCaptionText(this);
    },
  },
});
swiper.autoplay.stop();

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.body.className = "visible";
  swiper.autoplay.start();
});
```

If you wanna delay the inital start even further, to match it with your CSS animation duration, you can use a `setTimout`, like this:

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.body.className = "visible";
  setTimeout(() => swiper.autoplay.start(), 1000); // 1000 means 1s, it's in ms here.
});
```

Live example here at this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/yousoumar/pen/PoRVjOp?editors=1111) I forked. References of used methods are [here](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#autoplay-methods) on Swiper.js's official doc.

Comment: I'm just wondering if I need to add a delay after that? If it takes 1 second (for example) for the page to fade in. Do I need to add a time until it runs? Currently I guess it is kicking in when the 'dom' is ready - but need to account for the effect?

Comment: You can do that if you want by adding `swiper.autoplay.start()` inside a `setTimeout` inside `DOMContentLoaded` handler. Test it, maybe you need to maybe not.

Comment: Sorry dude, I'm a bit of a noob! For that would I do `setTimeout( [DOMContentLoaded ..thing], 500)` kinda thing?

Comment: It's okay, I just edited my answer. Take a look please.